# Change URLs with percent signs back to their original language

Tags: fonts, html, unicode, wordpress

How can I convert a link which has percentages and dollars in the URL into its original language?

I don't want it displayed like the following

`http://tantrarahasya.wordpress.com/2008/09/30/%e0%a4%b6%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%b0%e0%a5%80-%e0%a4%ae%e0%a4%b9%e0%a4%be-%e0%a4%b5%e0%a4%bf%e0%a4%aa%e0%a4%b0%e0%a5%80%e0%a4%a4-%e0%a4%aa%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%b0%e0%a4%a4%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%af%e0%a4%82%e0%a4%97`

… on my Wordpress blog etc.

What exactly can I do to see it in its original language?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: Change the format of your WordPress permalinks to `.wordpress.com/?p=#`

Answer (score 3):

These are [percent-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) URLs. They convert all characters to a simple ASCII representation. This process is also known as "URL encoding".

If you only want to your links in their original language, look for an URL decoding utility (there are plenty of them online too, like [this one](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)). Insert the link, click "decode", and see:

`http://tantrarahasya.wordpress.com/2008/09/30/श्री-महा-विपरीत-प्रत्यंग`

This URL will also work, it links back to your blog and opens the article.

Comment: The server configuration is irrelevant. The browser will encode the URL before sending the request anyway, as required by [RFC 1945 section 5.1.2](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1945#section-5.1.2)

Comment: @grawity Is it? I remember that I once had problems with something like this, but thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a service such as http://tiny.cc/ to create a shortened URL, which they then map to the original and redirect the visitor.

I've just done one for you: http://tiny.cc/h954l